# How can i get follower count in a previous date?

Tags: twitter

I want to get a user's follower count that belongs to a previous date. I couldn't see an api method to do that in [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1). However, some applications can do that like [twitaholic](http://twitaholic.com/BarackObama/). You can think that this sites store users followers count periodically but i dont think so. How do they get followers count in a previous date?

Comment: Why don't you think they get this periodically? I would assume they do, as there is an API to get the current count.

Comment: @RowlandShaw , Besause i have searched some users who is in my country and they have not much followers. Even so this site shows me their previous dates' followers count. I think scanning all twitter users periodically is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they only have historical follower counts for one of my twitter accounts for today. This would lead me to assume that they periodically poll for follower counts for accounts that users of their website search for.

As such, I'd suggest following a similar approach for your use case

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a programatic way to do it. Here's another way:

Use the way back machine, it periodically takes snapshots of sites: https://web.archive.org/

1. Paste the twitter url for the account you want to get their follower count
2. Navigate to a date in the past and collect the follower count
3. If you want to model twitter follower growth, you can use a linear model to connect the points that you get data for.